# python работа с excel workbooks

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Как (возможно ли)  работать с открытыми книгами excel в python?
Как (возможно ли) "зацепиться" за активную книгу?
openpyxl установлен
Книги открыты excel'ем
зацепиться значит получить ссылку на ActiveWorkbook в программе

Comment: Вы можете уточнить вопрос? Как / чем открыты книги? Что значит зацепиться?